# Url.Action how to override parameter from context?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

Here's the way I am doing it right now:

```
// Snippet 1
var indexUrl = Url.Action("Index", new {id = " "}).Replace("%20", string.Empty);
```

As you can infer from the above code, I have a controller, let's call it Home, with an index method that has an optional id.

This code:

```
// Snippet 2
var indexUrl = Url.Action("Index", new {id = 123 });
```

produces "/home/123", which is what I expect. However, this code:

```
// Snippet 3
var indexUrl = Url.Action("Index");
```

does not just return "/home" as I would have thought. Instead, I get one of these two results:

1) If I am already on page "/home/123", code from snippet 3 will still return "home/123" because from what I have read Action.Url will pick "id" from the request context.

2) If I am on another page, I don't even get "/home", but an empty value.

As you can see in the code from snippet 1, my temporary fix is that I am adding a space in the id param and then removing it with the replace method before using the url, which is quite ugly.

The answers I have already review seem to imply that this is all by design, but they are answers from 2012 so I'm hoping that new/better ways than the above have made it to .Net Core? All I need is the ability to tell Url.Action that I want id to be null so that it can simply return the base path without the optional parameter, in this case "/home"

Comment: I suspect you have a database and the code that saved data in the database did not trim values (removing spaces) before saving.  So the issue is with the data in the database and not your code.  The best way of fixing is removing the spaces in the database.

Comment: @jdweng databases have nothing to do with the above. This is a question about how the Url.Action function works and how to accomplish what I explained in the question without having to resort to that space and replace trick.

Comment: What if you add a trailing slash "/" to your urls? like instead of an empty string just add a forward slash ... not sure if it will work but worth the try

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro I'm sure it can work in a number of ways, but it's still technically a "hack", and what I'm trying to find out through this answer is whether there's a native/idiomatic way to accomplish what I'm doing without having to set fake parameters values whether it's a space or a slash

Comment: well there you could match two routes to one action.  after all they are different routs